# Url in Django 2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I still don't understand how URLs work in Django 1.x very well, and am having trouble doing so in Django 2.x.

Could someone help with with how to translate this to Django 2.x?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `url()` with `re_path()` (regular expression path) in Django 2.0. So you'd do this instead:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

The new `path()` function is useful for more simple URLs than this one.